# One Click to Open Two Collapsible Panels that are in Two Separate Accordions(Panel-Group)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion, panel, collapsable

I have two separated accordions (Bootstrap 3). And i want to open the same collapsible panel in the both accordions with only single click. I tried it with the same "ID" for the both collapsible panels, but when i click - only the panel from the first accordion is opened.

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
 <div class="panel">
  <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne"> // 1* i want when i click this 2*
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
 <div class="panel">
  <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne"> // 2* this to be open too
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

So, could i achieve that with modifying the "href" property (*if its possible of course*) or i need to write some JQuery with `onclick` event to do something like `addClass` to the element with class *collapse*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found a solution from an existing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27735454/5376197)- Raphael Serota says:

> "You can manually toggle the accordion with
>   `$('#myAccordion').collapse('toggle')`"

.
So I write my script like this:

```
$('.panel-heading').click(function(){

    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    if($(href + "Dyn").hasClass("in")){
            $(href + "Dyn").collapse("toggle");
        }else{
            $(href + "Dyn").collapse("toggle");
        }
});
```

This works just like my previous solution but keeps the animation running .

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Bootstraps](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) `.collapse('toggle')` to acheive this. See example.

```js
$('.panel-default').on('click', function() {
  $('.panel-collapse').collapse('toggle');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>

    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put
        a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>

    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put
        a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i was talking about two separate accordions, and when i click number 3 panel of accordion ONE, the number 3 panel from accordion TWO to be opened at the same time, your answer is well, but not solving my problem.Anyway tank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution (**but this one dont suit my needs**) this way - with similiar IDs on "href" attributes and accesing them this way:

```
$('.panel-heading').click(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if($(href + "Dyn").hasClass("in")){
            $(href + "Dyn").removeClass("in");
        }else{
            $(href + "Dyn").addClass("in");
        }
    });
```

With this method you loose the second collapsing animation! **IMPORTANT**